# 3D wind vector plot help/guidance

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d, python-xarray, weather

I have vertical profiles of atmospheric variables including winds (u,v,w). I have been trying to use matplotlib quiver function which works but the vector arrow heads aren't visible. I don't know if python is the right choice for 3D plotting but it is what I know, I am welcome to any advice to improve or different programs/languages to use.

```
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

# profiles, coords are lat, lon, altitude, with time as dim.   
ds = xr.open_dataset('profile1.nc')
ds2 = xr.open_dataset('profile2.nc')
ds#... = etc...

# model data that I'm using to get the terrain data
terrain_data = xr.open_dataset('path/to/my/data/wrfout_d01_2022-04-23_18:00:00')
 
   
# Create the 3D plot
fig = figure(figsize=(20, 20))

ax = plt.axes(projection="3d", zlim=[0, 10000],computed_zorder=False)
# Here I'm trimming the grid so the plot doesn't look so bad
x = terrain_data.XLONG[0,250:450,150:300]#[0,0:200,:]
y = terrain_data.XLAT[0,250:450,150:300]#[0,0:200,:]
terrain = terrain_data.HGT[0,250:450,150:300]#[0,0:200,:]

#plot the terrain surface
ax.plot_surface(x.data, y.data, terrain, rstride=1, cstride=1,
                facecolors=plt.cm.terrain(terrain/np.max(terrain)))
#scatter plot of wind speed for the profile
scatter = ax.scatter(ds.lon, ds.lat, ds.alt, c=ds.wspd, cmap='Oranges', marker='o',vmin = 0, vmax = 20)
#vector plotting
ax.quiver(ds.lon[::7], ds.lat[::7], ds.alt[::7], ds.u_wind[::7], ds.v_wind[::7], ds.w_wind[::7], color='k', normalize=True, length=.1,pivot='tip')

#the other profile
ax.scatter(ds2.lon, ds2.lat, ds2.alt, c=ds2.wspd, cmap='Oranges', marker='o',vmin = 0, vmax = 20)
ax.quiver(ds2.lon[::7], ds2.lat[::7], ds2.alt[::7], ds2.u_wind[::7], ds2.v_wind[::7], ds2.w_wind[::7], color='k', normalize=True, length=.1,pivot='tip')

#scatter plot of wind speed for the profile
scatter = ax.scatter(ds3.lon, ds3.lat, ds3.alt, c=ds3.wspd, cmap='Oranges', marker='o',vmin = 0, vmax = 20)
#vector plotting
ax.quiver(ds3.lon[::7], ds3.lat[::7], ds3.alt[::7], ds3.u_wind[::7], ds3.v_wind[::7], ds3.w_wind[::7], color='k', normalize=True, length=.1,pivot='tip')


#scatter plot of wind speed for the profile
scatter = ax.scatter(ds4.lon, ds4.lat, ds4.alt, c=ds4.wspd, cmap='Oranges', marker='o',vmin = 0, vmax = 20)
#vector plotting
ax.quiver(ds4.lon[::8], ds4.lat[::8], ds4.alt[::8], ds4.u_wind[::8], ds4.v_wind[::8], ds4.w_wind[::8], color='k', normalize=True, length=.1,pivot='tip')


#scatter plot of wind speed for the profile
scatter = ax.scatter(ds5.lon, ds5.lat, ds5.alt, c=ds5.wspd, cmap='Oranges', marker='o',vmin = 0, vmax = 20)
#vector plotting
ax.quiver(ds5.lon[::10], ds5.lat[::10], ds5.alt[::10], ds5.u_wind[::10], ds5.v_wind[::10], ds5.w_wind[::10], color='k', normalize=True, length=.1,pivot='tip')

ax.set_zlim(0,4000)
# formatting etc.
ax.set_xlabel('Longitude')
ax.set_ylabel('Latitude')
ax.set_zlabel('Altitude (m)')
ax.set_title('Dropsonde Wind Speed and Terrain')
fig.colorbar(scatter, label='Wind Speed (m/s)', shrink = 0.6)
ax.view_init(elev=25, azim=165)  # Set view angle

plt.show()
```

[image: 3d figure of atmospheric profiles and model terrain data]

I am currently using matplotlib version 3.6.2, and am doing the all of my coding on my university HPC jupyterhub, but may be able to convince them to make me a specific environment if needed.

I want to be able to visualize the winds in 3D space with arrows showing wind direction to better show the complex 3D aspects of what is going on in the atmosphere during this event. I have done some preliminary investigation of other packages like pyvista and Mayavi but currently do not have access to using them. If they would be able to make similar and/or better plot I can work with IT to get either packages working.

Comment: Potentially to do with the short `length`. Try removing `length` or setting it to 1, and worth also setting `arrow_length_ratio=0.5` - are the tips any more visible in this case?